# Extract values from a raster (imported as a NetCDF file) to table - problematic date/time column

Tags: netcdf, extract, date, multi-values, sample

I have a NetCDF file with sea surface height data, which I imported into ArcMap as a raster. I plotted the points and extracted the values at each location using the sample tool. In the raster, each value was measured at a specific time, e.g. 09/10/2023 12:15:00 AM.
In the associated produced column in the table, only the date (e.g. 09/10/2023) appears, the time is set to 00:00:00 in all rows. Do you know any way to extract the correct time at each location?

1st picture = Layer properties showing that date & time is recorded [image]
2nd picture = produced table after using the sample tool. Only date is shown.
[image]

Comment: Extracting to what format, please? It is important. Some formats don't support Date&Time values together. You may need to store both separately.

Comment: I attempted to extract the values into a table (as shown on the above example). What format would support them? Thanks!